# React: performance of rendering a list as hard-coded vs a loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance

Say I'm building a nav component which has 3 static links. Is there a difference in terms of performance between hard-coding the links or looping over an array? I would assume that, while the latter is cleaner code (less duplication), the former is cheaper in terms of processing.

Hard-coded:

```
const Nav = () => (
  <ul>
    <li>First link</li>
    <li>Second link</li>
    <li>Third link</li>
  </ul>
)
```

Loop:

```
const LINKS = [
  'First link',
  'Second link',
  'Third link'
]

const Nav = () => (
  <ul>
    {
      LINKS.map(link => <li key={link}>{link}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)
```

This is a simple example but I'm also curious about how more complex structures would be affected (eg: a complete website rendered based on a config file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a difference?

- Yes, hardcoded is faster. (just executing the already-parsed JSX instead of dynamic construction of the JSX *and then* execute)

Is that difference noticeable? Probably not unless:

1. You have many *many* elements (thousands?) created from that config
2. This is a component re-rendering very *very* often
3. If the process breaks some memoization (for example by making some memoized component prop have a different value each time, instead of the same value) which would cause a lot more re-rendering of child components

Best way is profile / measure the actual difference

Comment: Just to be clear, *JSX* is parsed and transformed by something like [`@babel/plugin-transform-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#react-automatic-runtime) into function calls at build time. The main difference is between a pre-populated `children` array and one that is constructed at render time.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification, I meant by JSX, what it becomes in the browser. (the compile step does not influence runtime performance) It is parsed by the browser JS engine at load time, and then nothing else happens on render, just function calls - as opposed to running a loop first.